# How to print Pythagorean pyramid in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this program to print Pythagorean pyramid with its triangular shape. It can print it up to certain point (until 2 digit numbers appear). After that shape is distorted. How can I correct this?

```
l=[[1],[1,1]]
n=int(raw_input("Number:"))
for x in range(2,n):
    l2=[1,]
    for y in range(x-1):
        l2.append(l[x-1][y]+l[x-1][y+1])
    l2.append(1)
    l.append(l2)
for x in range(n):
    print " "*(n-x-1),
    for y in l[x]:
        print y,
    print
```

Comment: There is no way to print letters at fractional positions when using console. You may consider using a graphical tool like `pygame`.

Comment: (1) I think it's called [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). Not Pythagorean pyramid? (2) Since you store the whole triangle, why not determine the position of upper level from the bottom level?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pad your output with spaces. Note that the number of spaces is a function of the longest length you'll print; if you pad with one space, your output will again be wrong once you start printing three digit numbers.